# Spring MVC + security + OAuth2 userInfoEndpoint() not work

Tags: java, spring, security, model-view-controller, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to login as Spring MVC + security + OAuth2.

The current authentication status is successfully received and user information can be obtained.

I want to get user information so I write `userInfoEndpoint`, but `userInfoEndPoint` is not being called at all.

On the other hand `successHandler` is being successfully called and authentication has the user information.

So I have two questions

First, Why isn't `userInfoEndpoint` called at all?
In Spring Boot case, it successfully called

Second, How to get user information from the authentication of the `successHandler`?
The authentication of the `successHandler` only has this method.

```
Object getCredentials();
Object getDetails();
Object getPrincipal();
boolean isAuthenticated();
void setAuthenticated(boolean var1) throws IllegalArgumentException;
```

—Source code—

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
            .oauth2Login()
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                    .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                    .and()
                .successHandler(new SuccessHandler());
}
```

SuccessHandler.java

```
@Log4j
public class SuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                                        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info(authentication);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the sequence like this in SecurityConfig.java:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.csrf().disable()
        .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
                .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
            .and()            
       .successHandler(new SuccessHandler());
}
```

Because below code permits all URL and because of which oauth2Login() code is never reachable.

```
.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
```